# D3's scale not working properly

Tags: d3.js

Well, I'm starting with D3 and I'm trying to create a vertical bar chart.

I really don't know what's happening but some things are not working as expected for me (maybe because I'm just a noob on the matter).

I'm using line scales, works pretty well with axes, but it's miscalculating the height of the bars, for instance the higher values are not displayed (because of the low value of the result).

I've used the d3.max to determine the range. I really don't get what's happening.

```
var yScaleLeft = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(stats)])
    .range([realHeight, 0]);

.attr("height", function(d) {
    return yScaleLeft(d);
});
```

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/aKhhb/ Look at *** Scales *** and **// Stats bars**

(Just forget about the x-alignement of the bars, I will see that later, I want to set its height properly)

Thanks a lot! Y saludos desde Chile :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your input and output ranges are mirrored -- that is, the largest input value maps to the smallest output value. That is fine, but you need to take it into account when calculating the `y` and `height` attributes. Essentially, you had the calculations for both reversed.

Fixed fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aKhhb/3/). I've also fixed the x axis by adding your margin and half of the bar width to the computed x positions. Oh and you don't need `parseInt()` when doing calculations, only when you actually want to parse an integer from a string.